# not able to paginate using struts

Tags: pagination, struts

```
<table id="example1" class="cell-border" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Entry Page Name</th>
          <th>Visits</th>
          <th>Bounce</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <s:iterator value="table" var="dashboardTable">
           <tr>
                <td><s:property value="actionName" /></td>
                <td><s:property value="count" /></td>
                <td><s:property value="sum" /></td>
          </tr>
    </s:iterator>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

This is my code.

(Struts) I want to paginate my data in table for each 10 rows. Please can anyone help?

Comment: What did you try so far? The code that you posted doesn't do a pagination. Please post only  the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be populating data in a table , pagination in any grid has these following steps

I'm going to explain a simple but not so elegant method .

let's say you have 100 records , and you wish to display 10 records / page

In the grid (Table and other elements) you put a dropdown , which has 1-10 page numbers (since you have 100 records / 10 records per page) , which you can get by doing a select count(*).

1.Initially you display limited data , by executing a sql select with limit  clause , say you display 10 records initially .
EX : select * from patient limit 1,10 - get first 10 records 
2.Next user wishes to get patients from 5th page , hence he selects '5' from drop down and clicks "fetch" , backend you need to multiply 5 * 10 (records you wish to display per page" now you execute following sql query 
EX : select * from patient limit 51,60

now the records from 51 - 60 are fetched and displayed

this a simple and easy pagination which doesn't involve jquery or any  javascript , you can modify it by  removing page no dropdown and putting it for display  in a linear fashion by using many libraries .

Hope it helps.